# Generate hibernate mapping and classes from data source in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm new to Hibernate. I've created a database with several tables and imported it as a data source into IDEA. How can I generate now classes for my tables and hibernate mapping for them? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the [Mapping by Database Schema](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html#) help section.

Comment: Aaand that's why you don't post link-only answers. Maybe this helps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-hibernate-support.html

Answer (score 1):

From the persistence window (View->tool windows-> persistence) you can select it like that and then deal with it
[image]